# How to find specific points in a graph in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with how to find specific points in my dataset. For example, I have measurement data from an oscilloscope stored as a `.csv` file that I import in Matlab. After plotting it, it looks like this:

[image]

My question is: how can I find the specific points A-H in my dataset?
Sometimes the noise is quite high and Matlab gives me the wrong x (time) values for the max and min values. Any suggestions?

The code I'm using right now looks like this:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
clear all;

Data = csvread('Data.csv',100,0);

Data = Data(1:end-203,:);
mean_Data = mean(Data(:,2));% macht offset weg
Data_withoutoffset = Data(:,2)-mean_Data;
a = 1;
b = [1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4];

Data_smooth = filter(b,a,Data_withoutoffset)
[maxBBpks,maxBB] = findpeaks(Data_smooth,'MinPeakDistance',1000,'MinPeakHeight',0.5);

Data_inverted = -Data_smooth;
[minBBpks,minBB] = findpeaks(Data_inverted,'MinPeakDistance',1000,'MinPeakHeight',0.5);

figure
hold on
plot(Data_withoutoffset); grid on
plot(maxBB,Data_withoutoffset(maxBB),'rv','MarkerFaceColor','r');
plot(minBB,Data_withoutoffset(minBB),'rs','MarkerFaceColor','b');
ax = axis; axis([ax(1:2) -11 11])
title('Oscilloskop Signal')
xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('Voltage(mV)')
legend('Signal','Max','Min');
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

I cut a little bit in the beginning of the signal and in the end to make sure I just have the right signal.

I could also give you my first dataset (I can send it via mail) to see because the picture is just how the signal should theoretically look like. In reality there is much more noise.

Here is a plot of the actual data

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you currently using [the data cursor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html?refresh=true) to find the values? We need to know what you've tried. It doesn't look very noisy from your figure, but you could try filtering if it's a real problem.

Comment: I added some code I wrote and could also provide the dataset if you give me your mail because I don't know how to upload it here.

Comment: with this code I can find min and max but i don't know how to find Point A, D, E, H

Comment: It's not hard to do by hand (use the [data cursor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html?refresh=true)). Is that sufficient? Or does it have to be done programatically?

Comment: If it has to be done programmatically, you haven't described the problem sufficiently. We don't know how similar each dataset looks, or what makes those points unique/interesting.

Comment: It's true that I could do it by hand but as I need to go through a several hundred of datasets it would be really nice if it could be done programatically if possible.

Comment: I try to explain it more in detail. The voltage (A) is where after the first jump in the rectangular signal that I appliy to the circuit the gradient (slope) gets smaller till Point C with is the minimal Value. In my code depending on the noise overlaying the signal sometimes the minimal value is not right at the edge before the signal rises again (so I get a too small x value how could I fix that?). The interphase voltage (D) is right between C and E.

Comment: The voltage (E) is more or less the same than A just in the positive way. Voltage (G) is the maximum value of the Signal (here again I sometimes have the problem that the x Value is not right at the edge befor the signal drops again). Voltage (H) is where after the rapid fall the slope of the signal gets smaller.

Comment: The datasets are quite similar but having differences in min and max values and in the slopes (B and F)

Comment: thanks for the efford I hope it is getting a bit clearer now. I can send a dataset if that would help also to see how noisy the signal is

Comment: If you could plot a dataset and post the figure, that would help show the noise you're dealing with (or is that plot real data? Doesn't look too noisy). Without knowing how noisy it is, it's hard to make a suggestion. It's best if you edit the question rather than comment when adding information. There is better formatting, and the information is clearer when someone else comes to look at the question.

Comment: that's the actual data

Comment: Ok, now that I kind of understand, I'll write a quick answer. If it doesn't work, just comment on it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there might be two steps to a potential solution.

**Filtering**
Since the noise looks very peaky, you can probably use a low-pass filter to remove most of the peaks. It would be worthwhile to tune your filter to specifically target the noise frequencies that are showing up. It looks like you're using nominal values right now.

**dV or d|dV| Threshold**
It might be easier to identify the times associated with the start/end of a fast transition by looking at the numerical derivative of your signal. You can do this with `dV = diff(V)` in Matlab. It looks like your points are also at areas of high acceleration (the noise doesn't actually hurt this metric much). You could look at the acceleration/magnitude with `d2V = diff(dV)` and `dadV = diff(abs(dV))`, and you might find that all of your key points show up clearly on this plot.